# Hanging .NET regex with high CPU

Tags: .net, regex

Here's a weird .NET regex problem that I can't figure out. I'm trying to unparse some HTML in my forum app. I haven't changed the code, but in certain environments, the regex simply never returns. I can reproduce it in the app:

line 66: https://github.com/POPWorldMedia/POPForums/blob/master/PopForums/Services/TextParsingService.cs

```
text = Regex.Replace(text, @"(<iframe )(\S+ )*(src=""http://www.youtube.com/embed/)(\S+)("")( *\S+)*( */iframe>)", "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=$4", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

The input string it's choking on is:

```
<p>This is an <strong>important</strong> <em>preview</em> of a post.</p>[quote]<p>This is a quote.<br /></p>[/quote]<p><iframe width="640" height="360" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/Zey3WWThErw" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></p><p>O look! YouTube!</p>
```

It will eventually time out here:
http://regexlib.com/RETester.aspx

The host process, IIS in this case, goes to about 50% locally (one core, I assume) and never lets go or returns. I'm completely stumped. The same code is running on one of my sites in Azure and it doesn't choke there.

Comment: obligatory: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3312

Comment: Yeah, I've seen that before, and I tend to reject it. This is a known and predictable pattern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `(\S+ )*` and `( *\S+)*` parts cause a *lot* of backtracking.

Consider replacing them simply by `.*`. It is not 100% equivalent, but I think it should work with what I feel like you are trying to do.

```
text = Regex.Replace(text, @"(<iframe )(.)*(src=""http://www.youtube.com/embed/)(\S+)("")(.)*( */iframe>)", "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=$4", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

You'll have other problems with that regex since it maches greedily. You might want to try this instead to make sure you don't have any problems if there are several `iframe` tags within your text.

```
text = Regex.Replace(text, @"(<iframe )(.)*?(src=""http://www.youtube.com/embed/)(\S+)("")(.)*?( */iframe>)", "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=$4", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

As always, you should also consider using an HTML parser instead of regex for this kind of task.

Comment: Yep, that did it! I knew it was a greed problem, but wasn't sure if I was doing it right. Thank you very much!

Comment: Why are you using `(.)*` and `(.)*?`?  If you want to capture those bits, the quantifiers should be inside the group: `(.*)` and `(.*?)`.  But I don't think you need those groups at all.

Comment: I mindlessly replaced the contents of the capture groups with `.`, my bad. But indeed, they might not be needed at all.

Answer (score 1):

Your only problem is this `( \ * \S+ )*`.

Engines get particularly annoyed mixing (zero/many`*` with many`+`)`* inside a zero/many group`.
Singularize the many in that case and problem is solved. ie:  `( _* _+)*` to => `( _* _)*`
***These are the only places where it causes problems***, especially when the many could match a lot
of different characters.

Always look to check that first, and don't get paranoid about backtracking.

```
 # @"(<iframe\ )(\S+\ )*(src=""http://www\.youtube\.com/embed/)(\S+)("")(\ *\S)*(\ */iframe>)"

 ( <iframe\  )                            # (1)
 ( \S+ \  )*                              # (2)
 (                                        # (3 start)
      src="http://www \. youtube \. com/embed/ 
 )                                        # (3 end)
 ( \S+ )                                  # (4)
 ( " )                                    # (5)
 ( \ * \S )*                              # (6)
 ( \ */iframe> )                          # (7)
```

Output:

```
 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 119 , len 121 ) 
<iframe width="640" height="360" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/Zey3WWThErw" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>  
 **  Grp 1 -  ( pos 119 , len 8 ) 
<iframe   
 **  Grp 2 -  ( pos 139 , len 13 ) 
height="360"   
 **  Grp 3 -  ( pos 152 , len 34 ) 
src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/  
 **  Grp 4 -  ( pos 186 , len 11 ) 
Zey3WWThErw  
 **  Grp 5 -  ( pos 197 , len 1 ) 
"  
 **  Grp 6 -  ( pos 231 , len 1 ) 
<  
 **  Grp 7 -  ( pos 232 , len 8 ) 
/iframe>
```